# A variable sended from Ajax dissapears when entering directly to the PHP File

Tags: php, ajax, variables, get

I'm sending a variable to PHP via Ajax.

The Ajax is triggered when a keyup is detected.

Once the Keyup is detected, I catch the value and name from the txtbx of the Keyup.

Then, I create the Request that sends the value and name of the textbox that triggered the event.

In `onreadystatechange` I launch a function that verify if my Ajax is on, and if my status is 200 the function retrieves me the values of the variables that I previously send, whose are getting back via the echo of the PHP side.

**All is ok TILL.**

Till I go directly to the PHP page and the variable that I sended from the client just dissapear.

Why, in the moment of the Ajax I mean when I catch data/send/retrieve everything goes ok but when I go directly to the PHP, the Variable seems to dissapear and I get a pretty Nice Notice: Undefined variable?.

Here I'm sending the code (It's spanish):

**Client Side with Ajax Request:**

```
window.addEventListener("load", iniciarEventos, false);
clase="";
function iniciarEventos(e) {
    var cajas = document.getElementsByClassName(clase);
    for (var i = 0; i < cajas.length; i++) {
        cajas[i].addEventListener('keyup',obtenerDatos,false);
    }
}

function obtenerDatos(e) {
    var ref=e.target;
    var producto=ref.name;
    var cantidad=ref.value;
procesarDat(producto,cantidad);
}
var conex3= new XMLHttpRequest();
function procesarDat(pro,can) {
    conex3.onreadystatechange=procesarElementos;
    conex3.open("GET",'../procesarPedido/pruebaDeRecepcion.php?nombre='+pro+'&valor='+can,true);
    conex3.send(null);
}

function procesarElementos() {
    if (conex3.readyState==4) {
        alert(conex3.responseText);
    }
}
// ALL GOES PRETTY NICE HERE!
```

**Now the server side :**

```
    <?php
session_start();
if (isset($_REQUEST['nombre'])) {
        $nombre=$_REQUEST['nombre'];
    }
    if (isset($_REQUEST['valor'])) {
        $valor=$_REQUEST['valor'];
    }
    if (isset($_SESSION['orden'])) {
        $_SESSION['orden']=array();
        $_SESSION['orden'][$nombre]=$valor;
        $nuevaOrd= new nuevaOrden($_SESSION['orden']);
        $nuevaOrd->validarOrden();
    }else {
        $_SESSION['orden'][$nombre]=$valor;
        $nuevaOrd= new nuevaOrden($_SESSION['orden']);
        $nuevaOrd->validarOrden();
    }
    class nuevaOrden{
        private $arreglo;
        public function __construct($ar){
            $this->arreglo=$ar;
            $this->empujarOrden();
        }
        private function empujarOrden() {
            foreach ($_SESSION['orden'] as $nom => $val) {
                if ($val=="") {
                    unset($this->arreglo[$nom]);
                }
            }
        }
    public function validarOrden(){
        $arr=json_encode($this->arreglo);
        echo $arr;
    }
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: Are you sure that, when you directory open the PHP page you are also sending the corrects get parametrers? Have you checked parameters cases?

Comment: I, the get parameters are already sended in the moment of the Ajax, and the PHP in responsible for the store of said variables in a $_SESSION['orden']=array();

But nothing hapends

Answer (score 2):

The data (variable) you are sending only exists in the context of your request, that is - while making the request. When you load the page from your browser, you launch the page in a new context. In the same way, if you made a new AJAX call, the old variable would not exist.

Instead, if you do want to access that page directly, you can either put your desired variables in GET or send them via an HTML form's POST, like so:

yourpath.com/procesarPedido/pruebaDeRecepcion.php?nombre=`pro variable value`&valor=`can variable value`

Comment: Hi I thanks for you time.

Look, there is something weird because when I use the following code it works, even using the same Js that trigger the Ajax, I mean the variables are stored.

Comment: session_start();
    if (isset($_REQUEST['nombre'])) {
     $nomb=$_REQUEST['nombre'];
    }else {
     $nomb="";
    }
    if (isset($_REQUEST['valor'])) {
     $valo=$_REQUEST['valor'];
    }else {
     $valo="";
    }
    if (isset($_SESSION['orden'])) {
     $_SESSION['orden'][$nomb]=$valo;
     foreach ($_SESSION['orden'] as $desc => $val) {
      if ($val=="") {
       unset($_SESSION['orden'][$desc]);
      }
     }
    }

Comment: Continue

else {
     $_SESSION['orden']=array();
     $_SESSION['orden'][$nomb]=$valo;
     foreach ($_SESSION['orden'] as $desc => $val) {
      if ($val=="") {
       unset($_SESSION['orden'][$desc]);
      }
     }
    }
    if (count($_SESSION['orden'])==0) {
     echo "No hay elementos seleccionados";
    }else {
     $arreglo=(json_encode($_SESSION['orden']));
     echo $arreglo;
    }

P.D. The File here is changed to orden.php don¡t worry about it.

Comment: Please provide the full PHP error then, and the URL you are trying to access.

Comment: Your alternate code works because you're assigning a value to $nomb (and $valo) if they aren't part of $_REQUEST.  Your original code does not do that.

Comment: Hi Bob. 

I added the piece of the code that verify the isset of the variables but now I'm getting a empty variable, it is going directly to the else part that assigns a blank value to the var $nomb and $valo

Comment: Yes.  As Noy Gabay has explained, when you load your PHP directly, $_REQUEST is empty.  It has values only when called using Ajax or with a URL that specifies the values.  Test it as she has suggested and it will work.

Comment: I don't know if I'm tired but I guess I already put the variables names with their values on the GET link.

function procesarDat(pro,can) {
 conex3.onreadystatechange=procesarElementos;
 conex3.open("GET",'../procesarPedido/pruebaDeRecepcion.php?nombre='+pro+'&valor='+can,true);
 conex3.send(null);
}

Why those values once retrieved aren't saved in the PHP side, it's weird because my PHP retrieves the value that I send in that piece of code, but it just dissapears when the Ajax/Function ends

Comment: I mean, the Js file never change, what I changed was the PHP side and whoops it just doesn't work anymore, and as I told you I validate with isset in both PHP codes, but just one code works.

Comment: I guess that the main problem is that I'm not getting stored the session variable that hold the variables.

Comment: If the session works it doesnt matter if I go directly to the php file because the variable session should hold the values even after the end of the ajax request.

Comment: Hi to all, in that moment I did not understand the ternary operator, now I fix it and I solved this problem by using the ternary operator, thanks to all and sorry for the long delay.

Answer (score 0):

From trudging through the comments, I get that your question is really, "Why didn't session handling work?"

You make assignments to $nombre and $valor if they're set in $_REQUEST.  If not, they're undefined.  However, you use $nombre and $valor unconditionally (that is, even if they're undefined) on the right hand side of assignments to $_SESSION.  That will give you notice-level errors that nombre and valor are undefined.

Storing an undefined value into $_SESSION removes whatever may have been stored there previously.

I suggest you step away from the code and write down in plain Spanish what you want to happen in the case where the $_REQUEST variables are set and also in the case where they are not.  You can then return to the code and make it do what you've written down.

It is good practice to use $_POST if your overall system design allows it because GET requests through the URL can be cached.  Also, it is easier for an attacker to spoof a GET request.

Finally, you should consider using PHP's ternary operator to get items out of the superglobal arrays:

```
$nombre = isset($_POST['nombre']) ? $_POST['nombre'] : false;
```

That way, you can write, `if ($nombre) ...` and the code within the `if` is executed only if $nombre was present in the POST (or REQUEST) response.

You can accomplish the same thing with `if ... else` but using the ternary operator forces you to think about the "else" part, which is missing from your original code.

Comment: HI bob you're a very friendly, and thanks for your time. I was thinking about change the way I'm sending the variables by using a post instead a get. I didnt really consider the option of the ternary operator but now it makes sense, that change the way I make PHP thinks about my coding, let me get into to the pc and try everything you tell me, if something new happens I will let you know it by this way

Comment: Hi Bob and everyone.

I get rid of the code and start replacing piece by piece and now it works fine, with the same JS-Ajax-Get file but now I can use OOP PHP in the server side.

But I'm having a non major problem, the session variable that store n an Asociative Array all the values sended from Ajax puts in the last position of the array a empty element.

¿Why is that happening?, I know I can use some PHP funtions to filter the array but I would like to know the origin of that empty last position, is always in the last position.

Comment: We probably can't tell without seeing your code.  Please edit your question to show us the new PHP.